# Using DATEADD and NOW() together

Tags: dax

If I try adding the following Measure into my DimDate table:

```
Past6Months = 
IF(
    FIRSTDATE(  'Dates'[FullDate] ) >= DATEADD( NOW(), -7, MONTH ),
    TRUE(),
    FALSE()
    )
```

I get this error:

> The first argument to 'DATEADD' must specify a column.

Comment: May be `DATEADD(MONTH, -7, NOW())`? At least this is how it should be written in `SQL Server`.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri - other way around in DAX: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634905.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Past6Months =
IF (
  FIRSTDATE ( v_Dim_Tid[Dato] )
  >= DATE ( YEAR ( NOW () ), MONTH ( NOW () ) - 7, DAY ( NOW () ) ),
  TRUE,
  FALSE
)
```

Comment: If Month(Now()) returns 7 or less this function appears that it would break because you are doing MONTH ( NOW () ) - 7 which would equal 0,-1,-2,-3, etc during the months of January through July.

Answer (score 3):

What also works: do what DAX is asking you to do. First put `TODAY` in a column and than refer to that column.

```
TodayColumn = TODAY()

Past6Months = 
IF(
    FIRSTDATE(  'Dates'[FullDate] ) >= DATEADD( 'MyTable'[TodayColumn], -7, MONTH ),
    TRUE(),
    FALSE()
    )
```